# Elastix "asterisk -r" command not working "-bash: asterisk: command not found"

Tags: command-line-interface, asterisk, elastix

I'm having trouble administering the current version of Elastix from the command line on a CentOS 6.3 box. I believe the command I'm look for is `asterisk -r` however I cannot figure out how to access the command line tools on this box as that command returns `-bash: asterisk: command not found`. Has anyone else encountered such a problem?

Comment: I had the same issue. Was able to get to the CLI using `/usr/sbin/asterisk -r ` arheops answer helped with this

Answer (score -1):

The kind of functionality I'm looking for can be achieved by accessing the web GUI at http://www.XXXX.com/index.php?menu=tools and entering commands there.

It is impossible to log into the Elastix box using ssh and then running commands like one would using asterisks. You must use the web GUI.

Comment: i am pretty sure you are wrong. Via ssh you can access asterisk, just need put full path to asterisk binary

Comment: I'm using elastix not asterisks. Perhaps I am wrong although no one else I've found has been able to get this done either.

Comment: Elastix is binary distribution based on asterisk and freepbx. There are no any issues log in into elastix via ssh. I am dooing that at least once per month for different clients. All my support is not local(via ssh).

Comment: I can log in just fine with ssh and all that, it's just that `asterisk -r` doesn't work even as root. I know on asterisk that supposed to work but nowhere in any documentation for Elastix does it say to use that... Just saying.

Comment: /usr/sbin/asterisk  have work. There are no need in any Elastix specific documentation. It just Centos 6.*. Use redhat docs.

Comment: Cunningham's Law does it again!!!